# Complex numbers ; $(1+i)^n=(1-i)^n$, Find $n$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $n$, if $$(1+i)^n=(1-i)^n.$$ I don't really remember complex numbers, but the problem is very easy I think.

Comment: What is $i\cdot (1-i)$?

Comment: If $n\not=0$ then $(1+i)^n \not= (1-i)^n$

Comment: Try writing $1+i$ as $re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @Roman83 Have you tried $n=4$?

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 5):

Multiply both sides by $(1+i)^n$ to get $$(1+i)^{2n}= 2^n.$$ But $(1+i)^2=2i.$ So finally you get $$(2i)^n=2^n,$$ so $$i^n=1.$$ Hence the solutions are all the multiples of $4$.

Comment: A slightly different approach is to divide both sides by the right hand side and consider $(\frac{1+i}{1-i})^n=1$. When multiplying top and bottom inside by the conjugate of the denominator, you'll arrive at Dubussy's answer...

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, think of $(1+i)$ as a 45 degree angle in the complex plane (lying on the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$), and $(1-i)$ as a -45 degree angle.  Raising a complex number to a power $n$ is the same as multiplying the argument (the angle) $n$ times.  You can see this by writing $z = (r e^{i\theta})^n = r^n e^{in\theta}.$  So if $n=4,$ then both of these angles end up being $180$ or $-180$ degrees.  This is also why integer multiples of 4 work.  Since they both originally were on the same radius circle $(\sqrt{2}),$ they will end up on the same circle no matter what power you raise them to.  Hope this helps you visualize what is going on.